# I want to attach link to words that match regex in pdf document

Tags: python, pdf

So I have a pdf file with many words that I should match (I already have regex). I need to attach inner links to those words so that when i click on one word. I'll be navigated to another matched word. So I wrote some python code

```
import re
import pdfrw
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


def add_links_to_pdf(pdf_path, regex_pattern, output_path):
    template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(pdf_path)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(file)

        for page_number, page in enumerate(template_pdf.pages):

            text = pdf_reader.pages[page_number].extract_text()

            matches = re.finditer(regex_pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
            if '/Annots' not in page:
                page.Annots = []

            for match in matches:
                print(match, page_number)
                word = match.group(0)
                x = match.start()
                y = match.end()

                link_annotation = pdfrw.PdfDict(
                    Subtype="/Link",
                    Rect=[x, y, x + len(word) * 5, y + 10],
                    Border=[0, 0, 0],
                    A=pdfrw.PdfDict(
                        S="/URI",
                        URI="http://example.com/word={}".format(word)
                    ),
                    C=[139, 0, 0],
                )

                page.Annots.append(link_annotation)

    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(output_path, template_pdf)


pdf_path = 'wiring-schema-sample.pdf'
regex_pattern = r'\b[A-Z]\d{3}\b'
output_path = 'output.pdf'

add_links_to_pdf(pdf_path, regex_pattern, output_path)
```

But It doesn't attach any links

So basically I know that my task consist of few steps:

1. Read pdf content
2. Match words with regex
3. Save those words coordinates
4. And attach link to previously saved coordinates.

The step i fail is 4).
Does anybody have any suggestions or can recommend some library (Pypdf2 and pdfwr didn't work for me). It can be any programming language

Comment: Suggesting PyMuPDF: has all the search functions, including words. Then define a dictionary "link" with the required key-values defining the link, and do `page.insert_link(link)`. Done.